# how i can put more lines in Line Plus Bar Chart using nvd3.js?

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

i'm newbie in javascript and i want to try to visualize data using javascript especially d3.js. I found example graph what i want to build in nvd3.js (http://nvd3.org/examples/linePlusBar.html) this is line and bar chart combine in one place,,i try to modified it to same like (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes), but i still can not do that.

My question is, how i can put more lines in in Line Plus Bar Chart using nvd3.js ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you draw a  Line Plus Bar Chart using nvd3.js, in the `JSON` you pass into the chart make sure, you add an attribute `"bar" : true` , to represent that particular data in Bars, the rest will load as line charts.

A sample `JSON` that's passed into the chart will look this :

```
[{
    "key" : "Bar Chart",
    "bar" : true,
    "color" : "#ccf",
    "values" : [[1136005200000, 1271000.0], [1138683600000, 1271000.0], [1141102800000, 1271000.0], [1143781200000, 0], [1146369600000, 0]]
}, {
    "key" : "Line Chart1",
    "color" : "#c2f",
    "values" : [[1136005200000, 71.89], [1138683600000, 75.51], [1141102800000, 68.49], [1143781200000, 62.72], [1146369600000, 70.39]]
}, {
    "key" : "Line Chart2",
    "color" : "#cff",
    "values" : [[1136005200000, 89], [1138683600000, 51], [1141102800000, 49], [1143781200000, 72], [1146369600000, 39]]
}]
```

---

**UPDATE**

By looking at your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZVLJ/) , I found the following in the console

```
 - Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/novus/nvd3/master/lib/d3.v3.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

 - Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/novus/nvd3/master/nv.d3.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

 - Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/novus/nvd3/master/src/models/linePlusBarChart.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Basically it had difficulty loading the `d3.js` and `nvd3.js`, I updated the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/shabeer90/mRubf/) with new links to the `js` files and it seems to work fine.

Hope it helps

Comment: thx for your answer, but default value of "bar" is true from nvd3.js, i have try it, but it's not working perfect as i want. I want make same as http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes,,i hope you can give me some explanation to how build it, thx :)

Comment: Can you add your code on a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so it can be looked at.

Comment: thx for fix my jsfiddle, but in the top of chart, list of name line/bar chart can be switch off/on, but when want to off line chart 2 it's not be off, how i can fix it ? thx :)

Comment: Let the answer above be related to the current question that's been asked, and accept the answer if it helped solve your current question. And post the new issue as a new question. Its a different issue.

Comment: Could you accept this answer if the answer solved the question you had asked, so it does not appear in the unanswered section.