# NVD3 Multi series line bar chart

Tags: nvd3.js

So the current Nvd3 [Line Bar](https://nvd3.org/examples/linePlusBar.html) Chart only allows 1 key for line and 1 key for bar. Is there a way to have multiple keys for line and bar, just like the standalone Line Chart and Bar Chart?

Answer (score 1):

You could use **Multichart**, then you'll have multiple columns with multiple lines. Take a look at the examples at:
https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/examples/multiChart.html

For multiple lines, just add each key you need, as it's proposed on this post: [how i can put more lines in Line Plus Bar Chart using nvd3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398961/how-i-can-put-more-lines-in-line-plus-bar-chart-using-nvd3-js)